# Is there any lightweight JDBC wrapper with these features?

Tags: java, jdbc

- Named parameters, just like JdbcTemplate from Spring
- XML configuration for JDBC connection settings
- XML configuration for queries. Something like Hibernate `<sql-query>`. See [Named SQL queries](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html#querysql-namedqueries) for an example

I'm thinking of trying to build my own, but I thought I'd ask here, maybe it's already been done.

Obviously I don't want to use neither an ORM nor JdbcTemplate.

Comment: What about [mybatis](http://www.mybatis.org/)?

Comment: @Tomasz Nurkiewicz thanks for the tip. I didn't know about MyIbatis. I've glanced over the docs and it looks pretty close to what I had in mind. I think I'll give it a go with a prototype project.

Comment: @Tomasz Nurkiewicz, two months later and I've grown quite found of MyBatis :). Will you put your comment as an answer; I'd like to accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about [MyBatis](http://www.mybatis.org)?

[image: a busy cat]
<sub>(source: [mybatis.org](http://mybatis.org/images/flow_med.png))</sub>

Answer (score 1):

I'am looking for the same thing, meanwhile try out DBUtils Utility:
http://commons.apache.org/dbutils/
Lightweight, open source and no dependencies.

Comment: Now I'm using ORMLite.

Answer (score 0):

Try [JdbcSession](http://www.jcabi.com/jcabi-jdbc/apidocs/com/jcabi/jdbc/JdbcSession.html) from [jcabi-jdbc](http://www.jcabi.com/jcabi-jdbc/). It's simple (as you want) and requires you to create a `java.sql.DataSource` before, for example (using [BoneCP](http://jolbox.com/) and [H2 database](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html)):

```
BoneCPDataSource source = new BoneCPDataSource();
source.setDriverClass("org.h2.Driver");
source.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:h2:mem:x");
String name = new JdbcSession(source)
  .sql("SELECT name FROM user WHERE id = ?")
  .set(555)
  .select(new SingleHandler<String>(String.class));
```

Comment: At the first glance doesn't seem to support named parameters. I find this feature really important. Besides, have I said recently how awesome MyBatis is? :) Thanks for your input though!